# how to call another view by Listeners function in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

In sencha touch , how can i call another View which display some info and which is already in another JS file and registered by "Ext.reg"

please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok..got the way to switching the views in sencha touch 2.0.0 application..
there are a Ext.container with a card layout named "navigationView" by which view switching is possible.

you can refer the documentation related to the navigationView here : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View

and also example over here : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/navigation-view

Answer (score 0):

In each view you can add an alias config

```
alias:'widget.mycontainer'
```

and then you can call xtype:'mycontainer' where you would like to implement it.

Maybe that will help